# Problem with UNICODE characters in substrings

Tags: memgraphdb

I've used the following code to create a node:

```
memgraph> CREATE (n:Node {city: 'København'}) RETURN n;
+------------------------------+
| n                            |
+------------------------------+
| (:Node {city: "København"}) |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (round trip in 0.003 sec)
1 labels have been created.
1 nodes have been created.
```

When I try to return substring sometimes Unicode character is shown correctly, other times not nut the count is off when it is displayed corecttly.

```
memgraph> MATCH (n:Node) RETURN substring(n.city, 0, 1);
+-------------------------+
| substring(n.city, 0, 1) |
+-------------------------+
| "K"                     |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (round trip in 0.000 sec)
memgraph> MATCH (n:Node) RETURN substring(n.city, 0, 2);
+-------------------------+
| substring(n.city, 0, 2) |
+-------------------------+
| "K�"                    |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (round trip in 0.001 sec)
memgraph> MATCH (n:Node) RETURN substring(n.city, 0, 3);
+-------------------------+
| substring(n.city, 0, 3) |
+-------------------------+
| "Kø"                   |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (round trip in 0.001 sec)
memgraph> MATCH (n:Node) RETURN substring(n.city, 0, 4);
+-------------------------+
| substring(n.city, 0, 4) |
+-------------------------+
| "Køb"                  |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (round trip in 0.000 sec)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is a problem in many languages; substring, length, indexof etc. all usually use [bytes instead of characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) for counts / lengths etc. So when you have a multi-byte character and you use any of these byte-based functions on them you're prone to get somewhere "in the middle" of such a multi-byte character as you're experiencing now.

Comment: I see. So that's the reason why � popped up instead of ø. Offset by 8 bytes that gets misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug and there is an [GitHub issue](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/307). You will need to wait for the fix.